# Phaser Full Screen Api Not Supported

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, html5-fullscreen

Currently i am developing application using phaser js.

Is this a browser compatibility issue or it is on the phaser js issue
where in the full screen api is not functioning

Here is code snippet that I use

```
if (phaser.scale.isFullScreen) {
    phaser.scale.stopFullScreen();
} else {
    phaser.scale.startFullScreen(false);
}
```

[Similar Problem](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1406)

So i tried what they suggest on the link

```
phaser.scale.compatibility.supportsFullScreen = true;

phaser.scale.startFullScreen(false, false);
```

Even the example of the phaser page it not functioning
[Phaser Full Screen](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/fullscreen)

> Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
>   startFullScreen @ phaser.2.6.2.min.js:22
>   phaser.2.6.2.min.js:22
>
> Phaser.ScaleManager: requestFullscreen failed or device does not
>   support the Fullscreen API fullScreenError @ phaser.2.6.2.min.js:22

I test in on 
Chrome 56.0.2924.87
Android 4.4.2

Comment: Hi, you can always check on http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen in order to see how well-supported a certain api is on your target platform. 

Personally i gave up on any android version bellow 5.0, whenever i need support on 3+ years old android i rely on crosswalk (which recently was "handed to the community").

Answer (score 3):

You can’t set the value of `supportsFullScreen`, that’s up to the user’s browser to decide.

Instead, query it and only start full screen if it is supported.

```
if (game.scale.compatibility.supportsFullScreen) {
  game.scale.startFullscreen();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tobe's answer is correct, but the error message also points out you need to trigger it from an event:

"API can only be initiated by a user gesture."

This may help others that stumble upon this error. Make sure you only call startFullScreen on a user tap.